# Table Design for my Database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, architecture

I am in the process of designing a very simple system for keeping track of a shifts worked by the sales team. Although i'm still designing and not done yet, I later realized I left out one important detail that I'll get into.

Some quick background first:
Each shift consists of how long the shift was (hours worked), whether it was the morning, afternoon, or night shift (or some combination), how much in sales were made for that shift, and how many tips the person made that day. I also keep track of things like whether it was cash or credit tips you received for doing your job well.

So one extra thing that happens is the sales team gets paid by the hour. For reports and running totals I am currently just calculating your income for that shift as pay rate (from job Position table) multiplied by the hours you worked, but I forgot the fact they could get raises! This means that if you get a raise, your income would magically increase (historically speaking)! I might've been making $10 an hour last year, and now $15 an hour this year - So the reports would be wrong.

My initial thought was to simply add a new column in my 'shift' table called HourlyRate, and that would be whatever the current hourly rate was at that moment in time. $10, $15, etc. Then I can just use this rate when i'm performing calculations

Do you all think this is an acceptable solution? Would it be weird to have a few hundred rows of sales all with the exact same hourly rate column for the same sales worker?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Hourly rate has nothing to do with shifts. Use a separate table.

Comment: thanks what should the relationship be between shifts and the hourly rate the person was being paid at during those shifts? I group together your tips and hourly rate as one unit called "income" for reports

Comment: You need to separate your table logic that is used for determining current pay rates, shift definitions, etc. from historical recordation of work performed.